# Visual studio 2008 crashing with VSS 2005

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, devenv, visual-sourcesafe-2005, comdlg32

I've installed VSS 2005 and added a VS 2008 project.  If I try to open the project by choosing File --> Open Project, then selecting Source Safe on the left and navigating to the either the .sln or the .vbproj, Visual Studio instantly quits with no errors in the event log.

I tried doing a devenv /clean and then /safemode and then I get an error dialog with the following entry in the event viewer:

```
Event Type: Error
Event Source:   Microsoft Visual Studio
Event Category: None
Event ID:   1000
Date:       7/18/2011
Time:       3:33:21 PM
User:       N/A
Computer:   PKCUSESBLTVPEPE
Description:
Faulting application devenv.exe, version 9.0.21022.8, stamp 47317b3d, faulting module comdlg32.dll, version 6.0.2900.5512, stamp 4802a0c9, debug? 0, fault address 0x00001ff0.

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
Data:
0000: 41 00 70 00 70 00 6c 00   A.p.p.l.
0008: 69 00 63 00 61 00 74 00   i.c.a.t.
0010: 69 00 6f 00 6e 00 20 00   i.o.n. .
0018: 46 00 61 00 69 00 6c 00   F.a.i.l.
0020: 75 00 72 00 65 00 20 00   u.r.e. .
0028: 20 00 64 00 65 00 76 00    .d.e.v.
0030: 65 00 6e 00 76 00 2e 00   e.n.v...
0038: 65 00 78 00 65 00 20 00   e.x.e. .
0040: 39 00 2e 00 30 00 2e 00   9...0...
0048: 32 00 31 00 30 00 32 00   2.1.0.2.
0050: 32 00 2e 00 38 00 20 00   2...8. .
0058: 34 00 37 00 33 00 31 00   4.7.3.1.
0060: 37 00 62 00 33 00 64 00   7.b.3.d.
0068: 20 00 69 00 6e 00 20 00    .i.n. .
0070: 63 00 6f 00 6d 00 64 00   c.o.m.d.
0078: 6c 00 67 00 33 00 32 00   l.g.3.2.
0080: 2e 00 64 00 6c 00 6c 00   ..d.l.l.
0088: 20 00 36 00 2e 00 30 00    .6...0.
0090: 2e 00 32 00 39 00 30 00   ..2.9.0.
0098: 30 00 2e 00 35 00 35 00   0...5.5.
00a0: 31 00 32 00 20 00 34 00   1.2. .4.
00a8: 38 00 30 00 32 00 61 00   8.0.2.a.
00b0: 30 00 63 00 39 00 20 00   0.c.9. .
00b8: 66 00 44 00 65 00 62 00   f.D.e.b.
00c0: 75 00 67 00 20 00 30 00   u.g. .0.
00c8: 20 00 61 00 74 00 20 00    .a.t. .
00d0: 6f 00 66 00 66 00 73 00   o.f.f.s.
00d8: 65 00 74 00 20 00 30 00   e.t. .0.
00e0: 30 00 30 00 30 00 31 00   0.0.0.1.
00e8: 66 00 66 00 30 00 0d 00   f.f.0...
00f0: 0a 00                     ..
```

Has any experienced this problem before or have any solutions?  Tried the usual places, but have come up empty handed so far.

Thanks!

Comment: It seems VS's cached data was corrupted. Try deleting files under C:\Documents and Settings\[userName]\Application Data\Microsoft\VisualStudio.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and installed the VSS2005 update (available at http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=291).

This resolved the issue.